# как сделать мерцающий текст Shimmer

Tags: android, textview

как сделать чтобы открывании активити мерцающий текст автоматически работал, не зависимо от View элементов

```
Shimmer shimmer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    shimmer = new Shimmer();
    shimmer.start();
}
```

Речь идет о библиотеке [Shimmer-android](https://github.com/RomainPiel/Shimmer-android)

Comment: Вы имеет ввиду [эту либу Shimmer Android](https://github.com/RomainPiel/Shimmer-android)?

Comment: да имею это, но у меня не получается автоматически

Answer (score 2):

Создайте свой класс наследующий от класса `com.romainpiel.shimmer.ShimmerTextView`, в котором в конструкторе с задержкой вызывается:

```
shimmer = new Shimmer();
shimmer.start(tv);
```

Для вызова с задержкой надо использовать `postDelayed()`

Comment: вроде делаю shimmer.start(tv); именно id (внутри скобки ругается) не может определить

Comment: дык, tv - это ссылка на объект типа `ShimmerTextView`